# Rails: CSV.generate and renaming headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm exporting a bunch of records to a CSV like so:

```
def self.to_csv
  attributes = %w(full_name first_name last_name created_at status)

  CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
    csv << attributes
    all.each do |lead|
      csv << attributes.map { |attr| lead.send(attr) }
    end
  end
end
```

But I need the headers to read like `Full Name` not `full_name`. I need a hash to match the names which is fine, but how do I write the new header names to the CSV file *within* `CSV.generate`?

**Update** Lookup hash.

```
def lookup
  {
    full_name: 'Full Name', first_name: 'First Name', last_name: 'Last Name', created_at: 'Generation Date', status: 'Status'
  }
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling titalize on the attributes array should help you achieve what your aiming for.

```
def self.to_csv
  CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
    csv << lookup.values
    all.each do |lead|
      csv << lookup.keys.map { |attr| lead.send(attr) }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: True, but if the header I want isn't worded the same then that won't work (hence the hash to look up the names).

Comment: If you are using hash, then you can directly call the keys and values. I will update my answer with what i mean.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Dope fix. Thanks!

Comment: Note: can lose the `attributes` array in your fix above too.

Comment: True, forgot about the array.

Comment: In this case, `headers: true` does not change a thing to the output. The parameter, for generating, seems to be useless.